# Incorrect Calc in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, calc

I'm trying to run the following calculation in JavaScript, `78.98 * 10` and the result returned is always `789.8000000000001` My question is where did that `0.0000000000001` come from?

I tried on several calculators, and that `0.0000000000001` should not be there. I did inclusive tests in other programming languages.

My question is, is there a logical explanation for this? If it is an error in the JavaScript engine where I notify?

Thank you.

Comment: Also, read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: i would like to introduce you to the wonders of float data types.

Comment: "I did inclusive tests in other programming languages" -
 maybe not as inclusive as you think, this is common to most languages (they might be fudging the results), check out http://0.30000000000000004.com/ for cross language examples of a simple .1 + .2 calculation :)

Comment: Thank you guys. ;)